# Passing a C++ Member Function Pointer to an STL Algorithm

Tags: c++, stl, member-functions, stl-algorithm

I have a member function as follows:

```
class XYZ{
public:
    float function(float x);
private:
    float m_DensityMin;
    float m_DensityMax;
};
```

Now, I'm trying to transform a `std::vector<float> foo` using the `std::transform` STL algorithm by passing the member function `function`, and storing the resulting values in a vector `bar`.

If I use the function as a global function, with random data that should denote the member variables of the class, it works fine.

However, as the function requires the use of member variables `m_DensityMin` and `m_DensityMax` of the class, I need to use it as a member function. This is what I've tried:

```
std::transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), &XYZ::function);
```

but I end up with the error in VS2010:

```
error C2065: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

As far as I can tell I'm passing only 1 argument. Any pointers?
Here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653165/c-passing-pointer-to-non-static-member-function), I've tried with std::mem_fun, as std::mem_fn is not available to me, but to no avail.

Comment: *"I've tried with std::mem_fun, as std::mem_fn is not available to me, but to no avail."* What problems occurred when using `std::mem_fun`? Have you tried using a lambda?

Comment: Unless it's a static function, you need a parameter object, and bind it to whatever `mem_fun` returns: `std::transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), std::back_inserter(bar), std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&XYZ::function), &xyz));`, [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1733c6da8b46abee)

Comment: `function` should probably be a static member function.

Comment: @ccoder83 VS2010 has `mem_fn`, try `std::tr1::mem_fn`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`std::mem_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun) itself only povides a wrapper for a member function, so that one will be invoked in the context of the first argument passed to its `operator()`. Having said that, you need to [bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12) the proper instance of `XYZ` prior to passing the function object to the [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) algorithm:

```
XYZ xyz;

std::transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(),
               std::back_inserter(bar),
               std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&XYZ::function), &xyz));
//                  ~~~~~~^      ~~~~~~^                  ~~~^
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1733c6da8b46abee)

Answer (score 1):

Unless the function is `static`, it needs an instance of the class to call the function off of. Because non-static functions should depend on the internal state of that class. If the function is independent of the class's state, it should probably be static.

If you had to leave your class as written, you could get around this by default constructing an `XYZ` just for the purposes of having an instance to call the function from.

```
std::transform(foo.begin(),
               foo.end(),
               std::back_inserter(bar),
               [](float a){ return XYZ{}.function(a); });
```

But this feels hacky, I would prefer that the function be `static` if it isn't dependent on the state of the `XYZ` instance, and only depends on the input `float`.

Comment: `foo` is a `vector<float>`, not `vector<XYZ>`.

Comment: I like the lambda version much more than std::bind. I actually forgot about std::bind since I learn lambdas and I'm much happier now! I also like the fact that you create the tiny object in place, although it may be better to capture it by reference if its size is relevant.

Comment: If the function IS dependent on the state of the XYZ instance, you could use a lambda to bind to the same instance of XYZ you called std::transform from. `std::transform(foo.begin(),
               foo.end(),
               std::back_inserter(bar),
               [this](float a){ return this->function(a); })`

Answer (score 0):

lambda version

```
std::vector<float> foo;
std::vector<float> bar;
foo.push_back(1.0f);
foo.push_back(2.0f);
XYZ xyz;
std::transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), std::back_inserter(bar), 
        [&xyz](float& a){ return xyz.function(a); });
 for ( auto & x : bar)
   std::cout<<x<<"\n";
```