# How to debug this C++11 thread code?

Tags: c++, c++11

I very recently started coding in C++11. Since I understood theoritical part, I thought of experimenting by writing code. This is my first program in C++, what it does is:

I am creating a class which has a thread type member and 2 member functions, of which one is a thread function and the other is a function which starts this thread function. But I am facing the below error. I did a lot of Googling, but none of them helped. I want to spawn 2 threads of "runThread" and they will update the `counter`. I know the `counter` is not synchronised, but I will take care of that using `std::atomic` variable once this error gets resolved.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class Application {
public:
    Application(int val): counter(val) { printf("value is %d\n", counter); }
    void start();
    void print();
private:
    void runThread();
    int counter;
    std::vector<std::thread> thr;
};

void Application::runThread() {
    for(int i=0;1<50;i++)
        counter++;
}

void Application::start() {
    //std::thread t1(runThread);
    //std::thread t2(runThread);
    //this->thr.emplace_back(std::thread(&Application::runThread, this)); Tried this, but dint work
    //this->thr.emplace_back(std::thread(&Application::runThread, this));Tried this, but dint work
    thr.emplace_back(std::thread(runThread));
    thr.emplace_back(std::thread(runThread));
}

void Application::print() {
    printf("Counter = %d\n", counter);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    Application app(300);
    app.start();
    std::cin >>a;
}
```

This is the error

```
../main.cpp: In member function ‘void Application::start()’:
../main.cpp:27:40: error: invalid use of non-static member function
  thr.emplace_back(std::thread(runThread));
                                        ^
../main.cpp:28:40: error: invalid use of non-static member function
  thr.emplace_back(std::thread(runThread));
                                        ^
subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: If the question is in c++ don't include the "c" tag.

Comment: `std::thread([this](){this->runThread()})`

Comment: Not directly related but your RunThread method will run continually since you are checking if 1 is less than 50 and not i.

Comment: @const_ref Thats a typo!! Thanks :)

Comment: Pro tip: titles are just for useful detail, and should be brief. Chatty material just as explicit requests for suggestions/help or how long you have been stuck can be omitted from the question entirely. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you should protect access to `counter` or make it `atomic`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler gives you a hint that the function you are using is `non-static` and it should. This is because in c++ even though You don't see it every class member function which is not static gets an additional argument which is a `this` pointer which you might be familiar with, this pointer points at the object that the function then operates upon. Because of that your `runThread()` function can actually be thought of as `runThread(Application* this)` and that means that the `std::thread` constructor does not know what value You want to supply for that parameter and expects you to provide it instead with a static member function that takes zero arguments.

One solution would be to make `runThread()` static and obtain the instance for example from a global variable (no-no) or actually tell `std::thread()` constructor what the argument is

```
std::thread(&Application::runThread, this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the call, use a `lambda`:

```
std::thread([this](){this->runThread();})
```

or bind function:

```
std::bind(&Application::runThread, this)
```

[Running example](http://cpp.sh/9lxpk)

Comment: `std::thread` is smarter than you give it credit for. `std::thread thr(&Application::runThread, this);` will do it; there's no need for that explicit `std::bind`.

Answer (score 0):

`runThread` is a non-static member function, which means it cannot be passed by reference. Instead it must be wrapped.

Replace

```
thr.emplace_back(std::thread(runThread));
```

with

```
thr.emplace_back([this]() {this->runThread();});
```

See also: [C++ Passing pointer to non-static member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653165/c-passing-pointer-to-non-static-member-function)